# Выделить столбец в таблице

Tags: jquery

У меня есть таблица вида

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>...</th>
        <th>...</th>
        <th>...</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Мне необходимо чтобы по щелчку по заголовку столбца в каждую ячейку столбца добавить текст.

Остановился на этом:

```
$('document').ready(function (){
    $('th').click(function(){
        // А что дальше?
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('document').ready(function (){
    $('#yourtable_id th').click(function(){
        var th_num = $(this).index();
        $('#yourtable_id tr').each(function(){
            $(this).children('td').each(function(td_num){
                if(td_num==th_num){
                    $(this).css("background-color","#000");
                    //или чего-нибудь еще творим с ячейкой.    
                }
            })
        })
    });
});
```

#yourtable_id - чтобы гарантированно правильно отработали циклы и поиск индекса в случае, если таблиц несколько.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('button').one('click', function() {
         $('#myTable tr:last').append($("<th></th>").text("someText"));
    });
```

Comment: Вы не так поняли. По щелчку по заголовку например 2го столбца, в каждую ячейку второго столбца должен добавиться текст

Comment: прошу прощения)